# How to make a background service?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I need to execute some tasks when my application is closed.
I have made a service for do this and tried many things, but i don't have the good result.

If someone have a tutorial or some path to follow, it would be great

This is my service:

```
public class TrackersImporter extends Service {
    private static TrackersImporter instance;
    private static long refreshDelay = 1; // Minutes

    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    private boolean isInit = false;
    public ArrayList<Tracker> trackers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static TrackersImporter getInstance(){
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new TrackersImporter();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("TrackersImporter",
                Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Message message = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
            message.arg1 = startId;
            mServiceHandler.sendMessage(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("TrackersImporter", e.getMessage());
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void addTracker(Tracker tracker) {
        trackers.add(tracker);
    }

    protected void showToast(final String msg){
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    // Object responsible for
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {

        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            addTracker(Runkeeper.getInstance(MainActivity.getActivity()));
            addTracker(Strava.getInstance(MainActivity.getActivity()));
            startImport(MainActivity.getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.getActivity().getAppUser(), trackers);
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }

        /**
         * Perform data imports.
         * Imports are performed only 1 time.
         * Additional calls to this method are equivalent to no-op.
         * Call init() then performImport() for each TrackerImportable
         * @param user user receiving the datas
         */
        public void startImport(Context context, User user, ArrayList<Tracker> trackers) {
            Context ctx = MainActivity.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            LocalDateTime now = new LocalDateTime();

            if (Preferences.getPref(ctx, "tracker_import_date") == "")
                Preferences.setPref(ctx, "tracker_import_date", now.toString());

            LocalDateTime past = LocalDateTime.parse(Preferences.getPref(ctx, "tracker_import_date"));
            long duration = new Duration(past.toDateTime(), now.toDateTime()).getStandardMinutes();

            if (isInit)
                return;
            if (duration > refreshDelay) {
                Preferences.setPref(ctx, "tracker_import_date", now.toString());
                for (Tracker tracker : trackers) {
                    if (tracker.isEnabled() && Tracker.isUserEnabled(context, tracker.getName())) {
                        tracker.init();
                        tracker.performImport(user);
                    }
                }
            }

            isInit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       ...

        if (ConnectivityUtil.isConnected(this.getApplicationContext())) {
            initGoogleFit();
            initTrackers(appUser);
        }
    }

    private void initTrackers(User user) {
        Intent trackersIntentService = new Intent(this, TrackersImporter.class);
        trackersIntentService.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startService(trackersIntentService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        ...

        if (ConnectivityUtil.isConnected(this.getApplicationContext())) {
            initTrackers(appUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you register your service to the manifest?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Yes i have registered in manifest and it works, but only if i'm on application.

Comment: Please explain what the problem is. Showing us all your code and saying you don't have good results isn't a specific enough problem. Explain exactly what you want to happen and exactly what is (or isn't) happening.

Comment: @DavidWasser I try to execute a task to push some data in my API, when the application is closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
First Create one launcher Activity which is like your Main Activity.
In Activity "onCreate" Method you need to start Service and Do Some thing if you wont in Service "onStartCommand" Method.


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Integer> list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,TrackersImporter.class);

}

public class TrackersImporter extends Service {
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

          // do something 
       Log.v(TAG ,"Service is started");
}
}

And also Register this Service at manifest.xml like this. 
   <service android:name=".TrackersImporter"></service>

if you like stop service
  stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,TrackersImporter.class);
```

Comment: I have edited my post with my actual activity for launching the service.

Comment: if you get this "onStartCommand"  Toast so your service is start and this is working in background and please check you stop service in main activity onDestroy if you did this so please remove this. if it is not so some problem in your others code like handler or something..

Comment: Actually i don't destroy my service and don't stop